# How do I get the first element upon certain condition in an Enumerator?

Tags: ruby, enumerators

I have:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
a.select{|x| x > 3} #=> [4, 5, 4]
```

What I want is "4", the first element that applies to the condition only. I know I could do:

```
a.select{|x| x > 3}.first #=> 4
```

But is this my best option? The `select` method will go trough all elements. Is there a more efficient way to apply this?

Answer (score 3):

Use [`find`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find) instead of `select`:

```
a.find { |x| x > 3 } # => 4
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is using [**`Enumerable#find`**](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-find):

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5,4,3,2,1]
a.find{|x| x > 3}
# => 4
```